# Search caching in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

Is there any use if I am using caching for search. I've a search in my site.

Anybody please give me idea about query caching in cakephp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply set your model's cacheQueries to true and cake will do the rest automatically

http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1069/cacheQueries

For example in /models/user.php:

```
class User extends AppModel { 
   public $cacheQueries = true;
```

Comment: This will only cache query results for the particular request itself, so doesn't provide for caching queries for multiple requests.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to cache find results, you can try this plugin: https://github.com/jeremyharris/cacher

Answer (score 0):

check [this](http://jamienay.com/2009/11/adding-automatic-caching-to-model-find-in-cakephp-1-2/)... it will help to set this catching dynamically, and understand when we have to use this...